# Will the Android M developer preview get an OTA update to the stable release version?

Tags: ota-update, 6.0-marshmallow, developer-preview

If I install the Dev Preview 3 on my Nexus 5 right now, will I get an OTA to the stable build or will I have to flash it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to flash it since Google only provides the stable release as downloadable image on [Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).

From [Official Android Developer site](https://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html#timeline),

> **Note**: Developer Preview 3 includes final APIs and near-final system images available by both download and OTA. At the full public release of Android M later in Q3, final system images will be available by download only, so you'll need to **flash manually** to your test devices.